# Help with my table structure

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make an address book. And have made my tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `list_`.`contacts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` tinyint(11) NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `zip` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `cell_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `work_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `fax_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(56) NOT NULL,
  `notes` text NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `group` (`group`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;


CREATE TABLE `list_`.`groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` tinyint(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=32 ;
```

My logic here is that I have all the contacts in the `contacts` table, from there I have a column called `group` that I use to filter the contacts into groups.

Then I have a table called `groups` that I'll use to keep track of what groups where created by a specific user and fill a  with these groups so they can move the contacts around.

When a group is deleted I will throw back an error no letting it be deleted if the group contains contacts. I can probably query the contacts to see what group they belong to and if they belong to the group being deleted then I'll move them into a group called Uncategorized or something.

But if they choose to accept and delete ALL contacts within a group then go ahead and delete the group and all child rows that belong to that group.

I am having trouble creating my Foreing Keys in the `contacts` table. No matter what combination of index and keys I try I still can't make it work.

```
--
-- Constraints for table `contacts`
-- 
ALTER TABLE `list_`.`contacts`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contacts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contacts_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`group`) REFERENCES `groups` (`name`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

-- 
-- Constraints for table `groups`
-- 
ALTER TABLE `list_`.`groups`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `group_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
```

Also, can someone help me with the ON DELETE and ON UPDATE. To help me figure out how I can delete all child rows that reference the `name` column in `groups`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you should have MySQL do so much heavy lifting, specifically deleting a group if it is empty.  Is there any specific reason to do this, i.e. can the group no longer be used if it is empty?  You could probably achieve this with [mysql triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) if you really wanted to.

As for preventing the deletion of a group that is simply done by the foriegn key on contacts that you already have on groups.  However I highly recommend that you use ids rather than names for keys.

What you are saying seems to conflict, however: you want to prevent deletion of a group that has contacts, but you want all contacts in a group to be deleted when the group is deleted?

Comment: yes, to your last question. Altho my problem is that when I run the code I keep getting errors that says: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`list_`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-7f8a_26084'>, CONSTRAINT `contacts_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`group`) REFERENCES `groups` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Comment: No, I am saying the last two statements stand in opposition.  How can you prevent deletion of a group that has contacts but also delete all contacts in the group when it is deleted?  The group has to have no contacts to be deleted in the first place.  What query are you running when you get that specific error?

Comment: exactly what I have in my original post, I do have other tables already in my db as user_id is a foreign key to users.id

Comment: Ah I see; are there any entries in contacts.group that are not in group?

Comment: Well What I did was try to reference group.contact to name.group. So that what ever the name of the group it'll show up as... oooh stupid me, I just answered my own question as a typed this ;0